# How can I change target folder to GAC (Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, gac, visual-studio-setup-proje

See this screenshot (sorry for Russian)

[image]

these are properties of primary outputs. But when i am trying to change folder (see the next screenshot)

[image]

there are only three standard directories in my list and I cannot do anything with them. Right-click is not working and all I can do is to close that window. Anyway my main goal is to install to GAC. I can choose CAG when using InstallShield installer, but I need to create my installer as a standard VS Setup Project. So how can I install to CAG in my case. I am sorry for Russian, if somme additional information or translate needed let me know.

**UPDATE:** I have found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x56s4w8x(v=vs.80).aspx but I cannot find the action menu. I fail to see why.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to do these magic things. Use tab for it. [image]